getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount fails all the time when Solana is under load
As part of the onboarding process for my project, I create wallets for users.
These wallets are fully onboarded to my game and are prefunded with the games native token. Users literally click 1 button and are fully onboarded.
However, when the Solana network is under load, getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount fails. In fact, getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount fails very often even when solana is not under load.
I believe this is due to getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount not having a priority fee. I cannot attach a priority fee or set the CU's on the function.
This high level function call which is supposed to create or get a users token account is highly unreliable, as it fails any time Solana is under load.
Is it possible for me to create my own Transaction object in which I can attach a priority fee myself so that Solana doesnt drop the transaction?
I use a Helius paid RPC, and whenever I can attach a priority fee to any transaction, those transactions go through almost every time.
https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/functions/getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount.html

Here is a code snippet of my code
const getConnection = () => {

  const endpoint = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production'
    ? `https://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=${process.env.HELIUS_API_KEY}`
    : 'https://api.devnet.solana.com';

  let connection = new Connection(endpoint, 'confirmed');

  return connection
};


async function getOrCreateRNGTokenAccount(user_pub_key, keyPair, connection) {
  try {
    logWithFileAndLine('info', `ATTEMPTING TO GET OR CREATE RNG TOKEN ACCOUNT FOR USER`);
    
    const userTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      keyPair,
      RNG_TOKEN_MINT,
      user_pub_key
    );

    return userTokenAccount.address.toString();
  } catch (error) {
    logWithFileAndLine('error', `Error in getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount: ${error.message}`);
    return null;
  }
}


If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to get an instruction for creating an associated token account if needed, so that you can append a compute unit budget to it. I'd recommend using createAssociatedTokenAccountIdempotentInstruction to generate an instruction for creating the account. You can follow a similar logic to the native code for getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount which you can find GitHub.
I think this (or something similar) should achieve your desired results.
import { 
    ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, 
    createAssociatedTokenAccountIdempotentInstruction, 
    getAssociatedTokenAddressSync,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, 
    TokenAccountNotFoundError, 
    TokenInvalidAccountOwnerError 
} from "@solana/spl-token";
import { 
    Commitment, 
    ComputeBudgetProgram, 
    ConfirmOptions, 
    Connection, 
    PublicKey, 
    sendAndConfirmTransaction, 
    Signer, 
    Transaction 
} from "@solana/web3.js";

export async function getOrCreateAtaWithComputeUnits(
    connection: Connection,
    payer: Signer,
    mint: PublicKey,
    owner: PublicKey,
    allowOwnerOffCurve = false,
    commitment?: Commitment,
    confirmOptions?: ConfirmOptions,
    programId = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    associatedTokenProgramId = ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    computeUnits = 250000,
): Promise<PublicKey> {
    const associatedToken = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
        mint,
        owner,
        allowOwnerOffCurve,
        programId,
        associatedTokenProgramId,
    );

    try {
        await connection.getAccountInfo(associatedToken, commitment);
        console.log("Associated token account exists: ", associatedToken.toBase58());
    } catch (error: unknown) {
        if (error instanceof TokenAccountNotFoundError || error instanceof TokenInvalidAccountOwnerError) {
            try {
                const transaction = new Transaction();
                const computeIx = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({
                    units: computeUnits,
                });
                const createIx = createAssociatedTokenAccountIdempotentInstruction(
                    payer.publicKey,
                    associatedToken,
                    owner,
                    mint,
                    programId,
                    associatedTokenProgramId,
                );
                transaction.add(computeIx, createIx);
                let { blockhash } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
                transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
                transaction.feePayer = payer.publicKey;

                await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [payer], confirmOptions);
            } catch (error: unknown) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        } else {
            throw error;
        }
    }

    return associatedToken;
}

